# Command 'du -h' but continue when current directory larger than threshold

Tags: bash, disk-usage

I'm looking for something along the lines of

```
du -h /var/log/ --max-depth=2 --threshold=5G
```

but to *execute `du` again on the current directory if the space is above that threshold*. Is there a way to do this in place to keep the order without reiterating over the original output?

For example for a threshold of 5Gb:

```
10.3G /lib/
8.9G /lib/lib1
2.1G /lib/lib1/files1
6.3G /lib/lib1/files2
3.2G /lib/lib1/files2/foz
1.3G /lib/lib2
8.3G /tmp/
8.2G /tmp/foo
5.2G /tmp/foo/bar
5.1G /tmp/foo/bar/bar1
900M /tmp/foo/bar/bar2
1.0G /tmp/foo/bat
1.0G /tmp/foo/baz
```

I wasn't getting the desired output when trying the command originally. Would a for loop or putting the du command within a function help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's not something that `du` can deliver directly, but a little bit of recursive shell script can wrap it sufficiently to give an approximation to what you want.

First, put all this into a file such as `/usr/local/bin/rdu` and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s dotglob

# Pretty printer
du_pp() {
    local value=$1 unitIndex=0 units="KMGTP"

    while [ $value -ge 1024 ]
    do
        ((unitIndex++)); value=$((value/1024))
    done
    echo "$value${units:$unitIndex:1}"
}

# Convert to K
du_ck() {
    local value=$1 l=${#1} unit

    ((l--))
    unit=${value:$l:1}
    [[ 'KMGTP' == *"$unit"* ]] && value=${value:0:$l} || unit='K'

    until [ "$unit" = 'K' ]
    do
        case "$unit" in
            M)  value=$((value*1024)) unit='K';;
            G)  value=$((value*1024)) unit='M';;
            T)  value=$((value*1024)) unit='G';;
            P)  value=$((value*1024)) unit='T';;
        esac
    done
    echo $value
}

# Call du, recursively expanding nodes greater than the threshold
du_rx() {
    local threshold=$1
    shift
    local starts=("$@")

    du -ks "${starts[@]}" |
        while IFS=$'\t' read -r size dir
        do
            printf '%s\t%s\n' "$(du_pp "$size")" "$dir"
            if [ -d "$dir" ] && [ $size -ge $threshold ]
            then
                [ "$dir" == '/' ] && dir=
                du_rx "$threshold" "$dir"/*
            fi
        done
}

# Call du_rx 1024000 /var
threshold=$(du_ck $1)
shift
starts=("$@")

du_rx $threshold "${starts[@]}"
```

Call it with at least two arguments: the threshold size expressed in `K` (default), `M`, `G`, `T` or `P`, and one or more starting directories. For example,

```
rdu 1000 /var/log    # threshold is 1000 KiB
rdu 1G /var /usr     # threshold is 1 GiB
```

Here's how it works.

There are two support functions `du_pp` and `du_ck`. The first converts a value in KiB into a "human readable" equivalent, which may use MiB, GiB, TiB or PiB units. The second converts a string such as `4G` into the equivalent KiB value. Both are shaky but should work in most cases.

The driving function is the recursive `du_rx`. This iterates across entries in the starting directory and calls `du -s` on them to obtain the summary size. If the summary size exceeds the threshold the function is called (by itself) with the current item as the new starting directory.

As for `du` all entries are output, not just directories. You can avoid this by wrapping this block:

```
printf '%s\t%s\n' "$(du_pp "$size")" "$dir"
if [ -d "$dir" ] && [ $size -gt $(du_ck "$threshold") ]
then
    [ "$dir" == '/' ] && dir=
    du_rx "$threshold" "$dir"/*
fi
```

like this

```
if [ -d "$dir" ] 
then
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$(du_pp "$size")" "$dir"
    if [ $size -gt $(du_ck "$threshold") ]
    then
        [ "$dir" == '/' ] && dir=
        du_rx "$threshold" "$dir"/*
    fi
fi
```